# VS code debugging not working with simulated IOS Device

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio, flutter, dart

I am using :

- macOS Catalina
- Flutter version 1.20.2 with Dart
- with the IDE VS Code

the issue I am encountering is I am not able to debug the simulated IOS device I have chosen. the device is iPhone SE (2nd generation). This is the following error I am receiving:

[image]

I have researched online and have come across several questions but they mostly deal with Android Studios as an IDE. Before this issue occurred I was able to install and debug once following the instructions from https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install last Thursday. I ran flutter doctor to see if there was any new errors:

[image]
but I believe those are the same errors I received when I was able to perform debug the first time. I tried restarting VS code, the simulated device, and my macOS but nothing. Lastly, I suspect it might be it something to do with the version of flutter I have. I will try to reinstall or revert to a pervious stable version.

this is a link to a question about the exited(sigterm) error to help anyone who comes across my question :https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31971

the code is provided by Flutter.

Comment: can you try flutter clean. 
Also if you want a good stable version, try downgrading to1.17.5. don't upgrade to the latest yet as it has issues with some packages

Comment: thank you it worked ! but I'm afraid I might encounter more issues since I'm startIng to learn flutter. once again thank you!

Comment: i encountered another issue that i will research tomorrow. this is the error: [VERBOSE-2:profiler_metrics_ios.mm(184)] Error retrieving thread information: (ipc/send) invalid destination port